# Usage of + in string in java

Tags: java, string

If String is not a Primitive datatype in Java and if Java does not support operator overloading then how is this possible

```
String x = "foo";
System.out.print( x + "bar");
```

It Prints foobar. How?!

Comment: Because the language designers accepted that operator overloading is useful, even though they wouldn't trust it to users.

Comment: @Deduplicator aptly said...

Comment: @Deduplicator -  they could have accepted string[index] as well. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: How often do you use `+` on strings and how often would you use `string[index]`. Not worth the hassle IMHO

Comment: @gexicide - For people who have come from C++ background, string.charAt() is ridiculously long to type ('ch'+ctrl+space isn't small either). I would prefer string[index] any day.

Comment: @TheLostMind: People coming from C++ will find a lot of things in Java ridiculously long to type ;). Typedefs for long generic classes would be nice for example, we can go on like this forever...

Comment: @gexicide - ya.. ya.. every labguage has its own advantages... :)